# Lower bound of bounded functions.

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Which of the following functions are bounded ?

a) $\frac{1}{x^2}$

b) $x^2$

c) $e^{-x^2}$

The answer was c. I am confused whether to take horizontal asymptote as a lower bound or not.

Can someone tell me if it is allowed to take horizontal asymptote as a lower bound?

Comment: Yes it is "allowed" ! ( for the lower bound of $x \mapsto e^{-x^2}$ ) the upper bound is easy to find.

Comment: @Atmos So we can take horizontal asymptote as a lower bound but **not** vertical asymptote as a upper bound right?

Comment: For me, an asymptote is the behavior of a function $f$ when $x \rightarrow +\infty$. With a function like arctan, it would be the same but for the upper bound $\frac{\pi}{2}$